# If you pay taxes using a cryptocurrency, is that a potentially taxable event?

Tags: united-states, federal-tax-law

With California and Colorado accepting cryptocurrency in lieu of fiat currency for paying taxes, there is a concern that paying taxes in this fashion is a potentially taxable event under federal law. But presumably, paying taxes is involuntary (unlike purchasing something with that cryptocurrency)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Paying taxes with cryptocurrency is a potentially taxable event under federal tax law. It is equivalent for federal income tax purposes, for example, to paying taxes in kind with IBM stock. See, e.g., [this IRS FAQ](https://www.irs.gov/individuals/international-taxpayers/frequently-asked-questions-on-virtual-currency-transactions).

You can owe capital gains taxes on involuntary transfers. For example, if you own a rental property and don't pay property taxes and it is sold at a tax sale, you owe capital gains taxes and depreciation recapture taxes on the amount realized in the tax sale if it exceeds your basis in the rental property (which it usually would since third-parties bid at tax sales).

Comment: I'm inclined to accept this, but do you have sources?

Comment: @moonman239 Fair point. Added.

Comment: Is using crypto currency to pay a vendor that accepts it as a currency also taxable in addition to the purchase you make?

Comment: @JoeW Yes. It is taxable in the same way when you pay a vendor that accept it. Calling it "cryptocurrency" is a misnomer. It isn't currency in any meaningful way for tax purposes.

Comment: So to fully pay in cryptocurrency, would you have to pay tax on the tax on the tax... and so on? The tax you owe is then the sum of an infinite geometric series..? Or does it stop after one tax on the tax?

Comment: @NickAlger What you do is use Algebra II to figure out how much beyond the tax currently owed you need to convert to pay the tax arising from the transaction, although the tax arising from your tax payment will usually be owed in a different tax year that the taxes that you are paying at the time.

Comment: @NickAlger: Ohwilleke's comment is expanded on [Determining the effective tax rate in a tax on tax situation](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/436932/3862)

Comment: @Brian err, I know how to sum a geometric series, it just seems absurd that one would need to do this to pay their taxes.

Comment: @Brian Good catch.